# how to execeute a command ls $PATH*.log and store result ina variable?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

hi how to store result of a "ls $PATH*.log" and store result in a variable like LAST="ls $PATH*.log" ??

thanks

```
#!bin/sh
var="$(ls -l $1*.log)" work correctly
echo "${var}" <-i can view list file

file= /my/path/$1*.log
var="$(ls -l $file*.log)" <- dont work
```

why?

Comment: no dont work in this post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code:

```
file= /my/path/$1*.log #you have already defined pattern here
var="$(ls -l $file*.log)" #this line will try to list /my/path/$1*.log*.log
```

---

should be fix to this:

```
file=/my/path/$1*.log #also removed spaces after/before = sign
var="$(ls -l $file)" #this line will tri to list /my/path/$1*.log
```

OR

```
file=/my/path/$1 #also removed spaces after/before = sign
var="$(ls -l $file*.log)" #this line will try to list /my/path/$1*.log
```

Comment: Can you tell that what are you passing as `$1`?

Comment: a file name like ERTAS_ASFAS_ASDASDE

Comment: so your goal is to search for `/my/path/ERTAS_ASFAS_ASDASDE*.log` files?

Comment: no $1*.log 
i have in mypath many file*.log and i want search for  "$1" *.log whre $1 is a parameter of my shell.

Comment: according to your test input...your script is searching for `/my/path/ERTAS_ASFAS_ASDASDE*.log` if `$1` was `ERTAS_ASFAS_ASDASDE` , can you add sample test data tht explains your end goal...that will be helpful to solve this query

Comment: ./test.sh AAAAAA_BBBBB_CCC  <---- i want ls -l AAAAAA_BBBBB_CCC*.log

if ./test.sh AAAAAA_BBBBB_FFFF  <---- i want ls -l AAAAAA_BBBBB_FFFF*.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128067/discussion-between-bigdatalearner-and-catanzaro).